# Pandas: Set multiple MultiColumns as MultiIndex

Tags: python, pandas

I generate an empty data frame as follows:

```
topFields = ['desc', 'desc', 'price', 'price', 'units', 'units']
bottomFields = ['foo', 'bar', 'mean', 'mom_2', 'mean', 'mom_2']
resultsDf = pd.DataFrame(columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([topFields, bottomFields]))
```

Now I would like to set the first two columns (with `desc` as top-level value) as index (**and as a more general challenge, *all* columns with `desc` as top-level value**). I've tried several ways, none of which work.

Here's the most intuitive (failure):

```
>>> test = resultsDf.set_index('desc')
>>> test
Out[4]: 
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [(price, mean), (price, mom_2), (units, mean), (units, mom_2)]
Index: []
>>> test.index
Out[5]: Index([], dtype='object', name='desc')
```

`pandas` correctly removes both `desc` columns (from "columns"), but none of these appear in the index. Instead, I have only one field in the index. When I try to create a row based on a MultiIndex, I get an error:

```
>>> test.loc[pd.IndexSlice[0, 0], :] = 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
[...]
KeyError: '[0 0] not in index'
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like need [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) by tuple:

```
test = resultsDf.set_index(('desc', 'foo'))
print (test)
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [(desc, bar), (price, mean), (price, mom_2), (units, mean), (units, mom_2)]
Index: []

print (test.index)
Index([], dtype='object', name=('desc', 'foo'))
```

Or maybe:

```
test = resultsDf.set_index([('desc', 'foo'), ('desc', 'bar')])
print (test)
Columns: [(price, mean), (price, mom_2), (units, mean), (units, mom_2)]
Index: []

print (test.index)
MultiIndex(levels=[[], []],
           labels=[[], []],
           names=[('desc', 'foo'), ('desc', 'bar')])
```

Comment: What would be the generic solution if I had many `desc` columns and wanted to set all of them as index?

Comment: One possible solution can be generate tuples, but it is really hard make nice general solution.